# Smashing a stack: Why is this code working?

Tags: c, stack, buffer-overflow

I am following the "Smashing the Stack for fun and profits" http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html .

**I wonder why my code is working though I wrote it to make a segmentation fault.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(char *str){
    char buffer[16];
    strcpy(buffer, str);
}

int main(void)
{
    char large_string[256];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        large_string[i];

    function(large_string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there something missing in the for-loop-body? That's kind of an incomplete Statement, I think.

Comment: bcoz even segmentation fault is not certain in case of `undefined behavior` :)

Comment: @junix incomplete, but not out of range

Comment: @LiranElisha Yeah, but what I wanted to say is that no initialization of the large_string buffer takes place in this code.

Comment: @junix if he'll do large_string[i] = 'a'; will the program be thrown?

Comment: @LiranElisha Yes. Not in the for Loop but by invoking function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just because your `large_string` is not initialized properly: it contains garbage, and its length (number of bytes till `'\0'`) is most probably much less than 256 (e.g. on my machine the fourth byte of `large_string` is zero so `strcpy` copies just 4 bytes).

Make it

```
for(i = 0; i < 254; i++)
    large_string[i] = 'A';
large_string[255] = '\0';
```

and you'll get segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the implementation **happens** to initialize `large_string` to all zero. And `strcpy` actually copies a null string.

```
for(i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    large_string[i] = 'a';
```

This will cause segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

you are initializing the string in `large_string[256];` and then go through it's items. you don't pass the limits of the array so no segmentation fault.

if you'll put values in the array, then the program will crash because `strcpy` will got out of range

Comment: This holds only true as long as one of the first 16 elements of large_string is a '\0'. Otherwise the strcpy should blow the limits of buffer declared in function.

Comment: The `large_string` is not initialized and contains garbage. `strcpy` copies data until the first `\0`. It's just lucky here.

Comment: true that, i'll add that to the comment

Answer (score 0):

you haven't initialized `large_string` properly.

After the for loop, add null character at the end of array `\0` that may help.

```
large_string[255] = '\0';
```

And it's better to initialize array rather as now it's putting garbage values.

```
 for(i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    large_string[i] = 'a';
```

---

**Edit:**

As in comments,junix said - More important is that there is no `\0` for at least 16 Bytes than having a \0 at Byte 255 to provoke a stack smash ;-)

Comment: I'd say it's more important that there is no `\0` for at least 16 Bytes than having a `\0` at Byte 255 to provoke a stack smash ;-)

Comment: Yeah exactly - Agree with you.